# SQL: Transpose rows to columns without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to transpose the following data using SQL 2008. Since Pivot uses aggregation, i do not think its possible to use.

Input:

```
File    Date    Metadata    MetadataValue
R1      2-May   Name        Custom Report
R1      2-May   Format      txt
R1      2-May   Type        Report
R2      2-May   Name        Standard Report
R2      2-May   Format      pdf
R2      2-May   Type        Log
R1      3-May   Name        Custom Report
R1      3-May   Format      txt
R1      3-May   Type        Report
R2      3-May   Name        Standard Report
R2      3-May   Format      pdf
R2      3-May   Type        Log
```

Output:

```
File    Date    Name            Format  Type
R1      2-May   Custom Report   txt       Report
R2      2-May   Standard Report pdf       Log
R1      3-May   Custom Report   txt       Report
R2      3-May   Standard Report pdf       Log
```

Comment: What exactly do you have against aggregation? I think you'll fine it much simpler and more efficient to use aggregates. You could probably do it with XML as well but not as easily.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid aggregating? It looks to me like your desired result set is grouped by `File` and `Date`. If your trying to combine the rows that share those values into a single row, that is aggregation by definition.

Comment: nothing against aggregation. just didnt think it was possible

Answer (score 4):

Still an aggregation, but you can use a simple `CASE` statement per value, grouping by `[date], [file]` to get one row per combination;

```
SELECT [file], [date], 
  MAX(CASE WHEN metadata='name'   THEN metadatavalue END) name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN metadata='format' THEN metadatavalue END) format,
  MAX(CASE WHEN metadata='type'   THEN metadatavalue END) type
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [date], [file]
ORDER BY [date], [file];
```

...or you *could* really use `PIVOT` for the same result;

```
SELECT [file], [date], [name], [format], [type]
FROM mytable
PIVOT (
  MAX(metadatavalue) FOR metadata IN ([name], [format], [type])
) b
ORDER BY [date], [file];
```

[An SQLfiddle with both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70268/11).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE t
 PIVOT (MAX(MetadataValue)
        FOR [MetaData]
        IN ([Name],[Format],[Type])
        )p
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ File ║ Date  ║      Name       ║ Format ║  Type  ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ R1   ║ 2-May ║ Custom Report   ║ txt    ║ Report ║
║ R2   ║ 2-May ║ Standard Report ║ pdf    ║ Log    ║
║ R1   ║ 3-May ║ Custom Report   ║ txt    ║ Report ║
║ R2   ║ 3-May ║ Standard Report ║ pdf    ║ Log    ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

### [`Working SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f195c/1)

Comment: Very neat. I always forget about pivots.